# Message parameters not resolved using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm working on a web application using Spring Boot + Thymeleaf and I'm using `@Size` annotation to validate a field of a form backing object:

```
@Size(max=50)
private String name;
```

By using the default error message, all works fine and I'm getting the following message:

> size must be between 0 and 50

Now I'm trying to customize the error message. First of all I've tried the following:

```
@Size(max=50, message="Max size: {max}")
private String name;
```

And it's working correctly:

> Max size: 50

But now I'd like to move the custom message in a `messages.properties` file. I set the property this way:

```
Size=Max size: {max}
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringErrorsAttrProcessor'  with root cause
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "max"

It seems the `max` parameter is null, or something similar...

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it is hard to tell where is the problem without your message configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `messages.properties` set like below.

```
Size=Max size {1}
```

Your field will be like below.

```
@Size(max=50)
private String name;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.